# Prove that $(1 + u)^{3/2} \le 1 + \frac32 u + \frac38 u^2$ for $u \ge 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I read an answer by a famous user here where he claims that $(1 + u)^{3/2} \le 1 + \frac32 u + \frac38 u^2$ for $u \ge 0$. How to see this without having to verify it is true? What I mean is it is possible to analyze the two functions or their difference to verify the statement but I am interested in a method which reveals how one would think about it

Source: [Find the limit of $x_n^3/n^2$ if $x_{n+1}=x_{n}+1/\sqrt{x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152173/find-the-limit-of-x-n3-n2-if-x-n1-x-n1-sqrtx-n?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is nothing but the Taylor Lagrange inequality: let $f(u)=(1+u)^{3/2}$ then for $u\ge0$ we have $\xi\in(0,u)$ such that
$$f(u)=f(0)+uf'(0)+\frac{u^2}{2}f''(0)+\underbrace{\frac{u^3}{3!}f^{(3)}(\xi)}_{R(\xi)}$$
and we verify easily that the [Lagrange remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) $R(\xi)$ is non positive for $u\ge0$.

Comment: this is what I was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

$$1+3u+3u^2+u^3<1+3u+3u^2+\frac{9u^3}{8}+\frac{9u^4}{64}$$

Factorizing:

$$(1+u)^3<\left(1+\frac{3u}{2}+\frac{3u^2}{8}\right)^2$$

$$(1+u)^\frac{3}{2}<1+\frac{3u}{2}+\frac{3u^2}{8}$$

Edit: As you have now provided a context to the equation this would by my reasoning:

He had a situation where he wanted to replace $(1+u)^\frac{3}{2}$ with a quadratic which was strictly bigger. So start with:

$$(1+u)^\frac{3}{2}<1+au+bu^2$$

$$(1+u)^3<(1+au+bu^2)^2$$

$$1+3u+3u^2+u^3<1+2au+(a^2+2b)u^2+2abu^3+b^2u^4$$

Comparing coefficients of $u$ and $u^2$ leads to $a=\frac{3}{2}$ and $b=\frac{3}{8}$

No fancy high level maths is required here.

Comment: I'm not sure what is there to reveal when Ian Miller simply squared the whole inequality.  This is such a standard trick that shouldn't require any elaborate thought process.

Comment: @Batominovski that's exactly why it is playing the question. I don't want to know WHY it is true but HOW to see it without blindly verifying it

Comment: I read, and don't understand what you wanted.  Maybe, you didn't know how to express what you want very clearly.  Please learn how to write.

Comment: "How to see without verifying it's true?"  is pretty much a garbage question.

Comment: @Batominovski what's garbage is your math education if you think that it is okay to see mathematical facts in this way. To blindly verify is what a highschool student would do on an exam. A true math enthusiast is interested in the thought process. I know how to write and I expressed in the question what I wanted in a clear way

Comment: No, it is not clear.  You could have written "how one obtains the upper bound" or something similar.  Yet, you opted to write some vague questions and made absurd requests like the one you asked from Ian Miller.  I hope you are not a math teacher who writes questions as vague as this one, and then blame the students who don't understand the questions.

Comment: @Batominovski see the accepted the answer. How did he understand what I asked if my question is vague as you describe? I added the "absurd" request because it is easy to see that it is true using many mechanical methods and I am not interested in that.

Comment: @user12013 That is simply one of many trivial approaches that can prove the required statement.  It's not difficult to come up that solution, which accidentally answered your vague questions.

Answer (score 2):

Simple proof: 
$$ \sqrt{1+v}\leq 1+\frac{v}{2} $$
for any $v\geq 0$ is trivial by squaring, AM-GM or by concavity of the LHS.
 If we integrate both sides over the interval $[0,u]$, with $u>0$,
we get:

$$ -\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}(1+u)^{3/2} \leq u+\frac{u^2}{4} $$
that is equivalent to the given inequality.
 If we take a sharper inequality at the first place, we may also prove that:
$$ \forall u\geq 0,\qquad (1+u)^{3/2}\leq 1+\frac{3}{16}u(12+u)+\frac{3}{16}\log\left(\frac{2}{2+u}\right). $$

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$ f(u)=(1+u)^{3/2}-1-\frac32u-\frac38u^2. $$
Then
$$ f'(u)=\frac34[(1+u)^{1/2}-u-2]=-\frac{3u^2}{4[(1+u)^{1/2}+u+2]}<0 $$
which implies that $f(u)$ is decreasing for $u>0$. Thus $f(u)<f(0)=0$ for $u>0$, namely
$$ (1+u)^{3/2}<1+\frac32u+\frac38u^2 $$
for $u>0$.